# Quotation marks inside bash script for pytest

Tags: bash, shell, pytest, quotation-marks

I try to write a script that helps selecting pytest options depending on user input.
Unfortunately, the scripts always fail because of the latest parameter, which relates to the marker.

I have suspect the quotation mark in the marker option to be the origin of the problem. Unfortunately, I cannot find any workaround.

Here is as MWE:

Content of test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

options=("-v")
options+=("-m \"not dummy\"")

echo "about to launch pytest ${options[@]}"
pytest ${options[@]}
```

Content of test_dummy.py:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.dummy
def test_dummy():
    assert(True)
```

Now the output of running test.sh script:

> about to launch pytest -v -m "not dummy"
>   =============================================================================================================================== test session starts
>   =============================================================================================================================== platform linux -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
>   -- /home/[...]/anaconda3/bin/python cachedir: .cache rootdir: /home/[...]/pytest, inifile: plugins:
>   cov-2.5.1
>
> ========================================================================================================================== no tests ran in 0.00 seconds
>   =========================================================================================================================== ERROR: file not found: dummy"

Of course, running the generated command

> pytest -v -m "not dummy"

Works perfectly. How to overcome this problem

Thank you in advance

Comment: `pytest "${options[@]}"` is closer, but won't work since you're passing the single argument `-m "not dummy"` instead of two arguments `-m` and `not dummy`

Comment: It does not work indeed, the last paremeter even seems to be ignored

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, but I think you problem comes from defining two arguments as a single one. Try to put all arguments separated:

```
#!/bin/bash

options=("-v")
options+=("-m" "not dummy")

echo "about to launch pytest ${options[@]}"
pytest "${options[@]}"
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually, a found a way of solving this. Apparently the easiest solution is to "recast" the whole command as a string, and make eval to evaluate it.

I replaced the last line

> pytest ${options[@]}

by

> eval pytest ${options[@]}

Comment: See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).  The answer by Poshi contains a good fix for the code.